# I want to set up a basic cron job that sends an email

Tags: cron, email

I am running OS X 10.7 and I am learning unix commands. I would like to set up a very basic cron job that sends me an email with a certain message.

How would I go about this. From what I have read, I should receive an email automatically unless I specify otherwise.

I don't seem to have the crontab file in the /etc directory.

Any help is more than appreciated.

Comment: I don't know MacOS, but usually crontab files are not stored in /etc. But anyway, you not need to know where they are. Use the `crontab -e` command for editing, it will know the location.

Comment: I think I have found that already then, I tried changing to the root directory then to /etc then list all files however its not there. As you say, its not an issue though. I have created a job I think that prints a line of text, but I don't know where the output is saved, also, how can I get it to email me said message?

Answer (score 1):

`cron` automatically emails you the output ( if any ) of the jobs it runs.  Of course, you have to have an email server ( eg. postfix ) installed for this to work.

Comment: Would OS X Lion Server work?

Comment: @Mike, I believe that is an OS product, not an SMTP server.

Comment: If I had my own hosted server, would this work if I saved the settings somewhere?

Comment: @Mike, I have no idea what you are asking.  You need to be running an SMTP server that accepts mail on port 25 and delivers it to the correct mailbox.

Comment: I have a website with SMTP email, If I used those server settings could I send email from cron jobs?

Comment: @Mike, cron doesn't take server settings; it sends the mail to localhost.

Answer (score 1):

You can send yourself an email using this solution:
http://mabblog.com/blog/2011/09/lion-smtp-postfix-relay-and-dreamhost/comment-page-1/#comment-264118

Note that the only parts that are NOT literal are references to "you@domain.com" and "username@domain.com:password". Provide appropriate values for them.

Leave the brackets in, don't change the port address (587) and leave "mail.domain.com" as is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a whole mail infrastructure for this to work. Personally, I use esmtp (a program that emulates sendmail) and procmail (a mail delivery agent), in this way I can get messages from cron jobs. However, if I were you I'd think twice whether it's worth the hassle, because mail servers can be, and usually are, a real headache to set up.